# How come the ls command prints in multiple columns on tty but only one column everywhere else?

Tags: unix, shell, ls

Even after using Unix-like OSes for a couple years, this behaviour still baffles me.

When I use the ls command in a directory that has lots of files, the output is usually nicely formatted into multiple columns. Here's an example:

```
$ ls
a.txt  C.txt  f.txt  H.txt  k.txt  M.txt  p.txt  R.txt  u.txt  W.txt  z.txt
A.txt  d.txt  F.txt  i.txt  K.txt  n.txt  P.txt  s.txt  U.txt  x.txt  Z.txt
b.txt  D.txt  g.txt  I.txt  l.txt  N.txt  q.txt  S.txt  v.txt  X.txt
B.txt  e.txt  G.txt  j.txt  L.txt  o.txt  Q.txt  t.txt  V.txt  y.txt
c.txt  E.txt  h.txt  J.txt  m.txt  O.txt  r.txt  T.txt  w.txt  Y.txt
```

However, if I try to redirect the output to a file, or pipe it to another command, only a single column appears in the output. Using the same example directory as above, here's what I get when I pipe ls to wc:

```
$ ls | wc
     52      52     312
```

In other words, wc thinks there are 52 lines, even though the output to the terminal has only 5.

I haven't observed this behaviour in *any* other command. Would you like to explain this to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is simply detecting that it's output is a terminal device and formatting output so it looks better on it. You can print out the same formatted ls output to a file or pipe with option -C.

How to detect output is a terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061575/detect-in-c-if-outputting-to-a-terminal

Comment: Oh is that it? I see. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. :)

Comment: No problem. If your curiosity is satisfied then I think you can kindly close the question.

Answer (score 4):

When the output of a program provides a list of some sort, and you redirect the output of the program to a file, or pipe it to another program, typically it is for the purpose of the second program to read the original program output (or the file), in a loop, 1 line at a time.

In this sort of case, it is almost always more convenient for each line that is read to contain one item (1 filename), or 1 "record" of information about a single item, rather than a number of different items that have to be split apart.

This is especially the case for filenames that can contain spaces because spaces are also the delimiter that separates each item (filename).

For example ...

First, I create some files:

```
% touch "300"
% cp "300" "301"
% cp "300" "302  304"
% cp "300" "303  305"
% cp "300" "306"
% cp "300" "307"
% cp "300" "308"
% cp "300" "309"
% cp "300" "310  312"
% cp "300" "311  313"
% cp "300" "314  316"
% cp "300" "315  317"
% cp "300" "318"
% cp "300" "319"
% cp "300" "320  322"
% cp "300" "321  323"
% cp "300" "324"
% cp "300" "325"
% cp "300" "bar  bin"
% cp "300" "baz  boo"
% cp "300" "def"
% cp "300" "etc"
% cp "300" "foo  mos"
%
```

Now, I get a "long" listing of the files I created:

```
% ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 300
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 301
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 302  304
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 303  305
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 306
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 307
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 308
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 309
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 310  312
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 311  313
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 314  316
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 315  317
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 318
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 319
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 320  322
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 321  323
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 324
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 325
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 bar  bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 baz  boo
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 def
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 etc
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 28 01:51 foo  mos
%
```

OK, so that is fairly obvious what the filenames are.

Now, I get a listing of the files by columns:

```
% ls
300  302  304  306  308  310  312  314  316  318  320  322  324  bar  bin  def  foo  mos
301  303  305  307  309  311  313  315  317  319  321  323  325  baz  boo  etc
%
```

As you can see, a program reading the output (and even a human observer) would not be able to pick out the correct names of the files and would probably think this is a long list of 3 character filenames.

If we pipe the output of ls into more, we get:

```
% ls | more
300
301
302  304
303  305
306
307
308
309
310  312
311  313
314  316
315  317
318
319
320  322
321  323
324
325
bar  bin
baz  boo
def
etc
foo  mos
%
```

While not very pretty, it is now much easier to pick the correct filenames because each filename is on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

The thing going on actually is that the terminal formats the output given by `ls`. The actual output by ls command is as following:

```bash
hussain@ai:~/test$ ls # The terminal formats this output by itself
text1   text11  text13  text15  text17  text19  text20  text22  text24  text26  text28  text3   text4  text6  text8
text10  text12  text14  text16  text18  text2   text21  text23  text25  text27  text29  text30  text5  text7  text9
```

Now, if I pipe it and pass it to `less` command, something like this will be shown:

```bash
hussain@ai:~/test$ ls | less # This means that the actual output is the below
text1
text10
text11
text12
text13
text14
text15
text16
text17
text18
...
...
...
```

So this means that if you give the same to `wc` or any other program, the above given output will be the one it will work on (i.e. Not the fancy terminal output). However if you want that fancy output to be passed to the you can use the `-C` flag with `ls` command such as given in @piokuc 's answer

In addition to this, if you want to see the output as it is sent to next commands (without using pipe "`|`" sign you can use the `-w` or `--width` flag.

So here is the difference between each of these.

```bash
ai:test hussain$ ls # The terminal formats this output by itself as it can be seen in Kevin Fegan's Answer
text1   text11  text13  text15  text17  text19  text20  text22  text24  text26  text28  text3   text4  text6  text8
text10  text12  text14  text16  text18  text2   text21  text23  text25  text27  text29  text30  text5  text7  text9
```

```bash
ai:test hussain$ ls -w0 # width 0 is the default behavior. it comes preformatted to the terminal 
text1  text10  text11  text12  text13  text14  text15  text16  text17  text18  text19  text2  text20  text21  text22  text23  text24  text25  text26  text27  text28  text29  text3  text30  text4  text5  text6  text7  text8  text9
```

Don't use `-w0` for performing operations on your files in your scripts.
Instead use `*` (`for file_and_dir in *; do ...`)

```bash
ai:test hussain$ ls -w1 # The output comes preformatted but in a new line. It is just like you force to see it in this way.
text1
text10
text11
text12
text13
text14
...
...
...
```

Comment: This doesnt really answer the question.